# @mediaQuery en controlador angularjs

Tags: angularjs, css

Es posible dentro de

```
$scope.body = {

  'background-image':'url("../images/fondo_mix.png")',
  'background-size': 'contain',
  'height': '200vh',
  'background-attachment':'fixed'      
}
```

agregar una media query?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Primero que nada te recomiendo usar boostrapp y te ahorras el problema del responsive.

Respondiendo a tu pregunta, pues si se puede agregar una media query, pero con ng-class en vez de agregar en el lugar donde lo estás haciendo.

```css
@media all and (max-width: 600px) {
   .positivo {
  color: #33f;
}
}
```

```html
  <p ng-class="{positivo}">
    En el acumulador llevamos <span>{{vm.total}}</span>
  </p>
```